# Error ORA-00920: Invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I assume the error is coming from the case statement but I can't figure out what's giving it such a problem.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT aim.student_id,
       coordinator,
       ac_class,
       email_contact,
       doc_date,
       doc_exp_date,
       notes,
       ad.name as "Disability",
       aa.name as "Accommodation",
       PERSON_ID,
       tse.YEAR_TERM,
       ATT_CREDITS,
       PRIMARY_PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION,
       ACADEMIC_YEAR,
       MARITAL_STATUS,
       ENROLLMENT_STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
       CALENDAR_YEAR,
       YEAR_TERM_START_DATE,
       YEAR_TERM_END_DATE,
       CASE
         WHEN (doc_date <= year_term_end_date AND
              doc_exp_date >= year_term_end_date) THEN
          1
         WHEN (isnull(doc_exp_date)) THEN
          1
         ELSE
          0
       END AS "Valid Document"
  FROM striker.saasta_prod.accessibility_aim aim
  JOIN striker.saasta_prod.accessibility_std_disabilities asd
    ON aim.student_id = asd.student_id
  JOIN striker.saasta_prod.accessibility_disabilities ad
    ON asd.disability_id = ad.id
  LEFT JOIN striker.saasta_prod.accessibility_std_accommodations asa
    ON aim.student_id = asa.student_id
  LEFT JOIN striker.saasta_prod.accessibility_accommodations aa
    ON asa.accommodation_id = aa.id
  JOIN dwprd.ods.std_term_status_ext tse
    ON aim.student_id = tse.person_id
  JOIN dwprd.edw.year_term_dim ytd
    ON tse.year_term = ytd.year_term
```

Comment: Hi, please see the case statement. What value you want to validate to the column ..
(isnull(doc_exp_date)) =?..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your join table names have three arguments, only two are allowed:

```
INNER JOIN striker.saasta_prod.accessibility_std_disabilities asd
```

Did you copy this from SQL Server, where you are allowed to prefix the database name? This is not allowed in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you need to replace `isnull()` function with [`nullif()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions107.htm#SQLRF00681) or [`nvl()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#SQLRF00684), and the second argument needed for them. Since Oracle DB has no `isnull()` function while another DB such as SQL Server has.

All their usage logics are similar.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Brian Leach, there is an isse with the way you are referring the tables : in Oracle, you can use `my_schema.my_table`, but using three dot-separated parts is not supported.

There is also an issue in the `CASE` expression:

> `WHEN (isnull(doc_exp_date)) THEN 1`

There is no `ISNULL()` function in Oracle.

In SQL Server, `ISNULL()` is used to check if first argument is `NULL`and, in that event, replace it with the second argument. The Oracle equivalent is `NVL()`.

But since you are using this expression as a condition, I suspect that you actually meant:

```
WHEN doc_exp_date IS NULL THEN 1
```